# Send string from PC keyboard to android input view

Tags: android, keyboard

I'd like to develop a tool to send string from PC keybord to android input view. When open any app in device, and press on the input view, then I can get the focused view.  using the way like hierachyviewer do I can get the focused view, using UIAutomator I can send string to the view. but Is there some method to input the string from Pc keybord to the view in real time just like input from soft-keyboard? anyone could offer some help? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [MonkeyRunner](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/MonkeyRunner.html)?

You can use jython, as follows:

```
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice

dev = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()
dev.type( 'This is sent to the connected devices.' )
```

All you need is some basic jython to read the pc's keyboard and send the characters using MonkeyDevice.type()

Comment: I'm not familiar with python. but I will try this way, Thanks. BTW, could you please tell me how to use Pyhook with jython?

Comment: Sorry, can't help with pyHook. I'm not sure it would work in jython though, because it's written in C, while jython is Java.

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for something similar so I made this tool for exactly nthe same reason. It is highly customizable. You can give your own custom key map too the tool or use the default one.

https://github.com/aakashsigdel/android-shell-input

Let me know if you have any questions